# Comparing multiple likert items across two groups - is the MANOVA appropriate?

Tags: likert, group-differences, manova

I would love to compare 9 multinomial (4 point likert) and 2 binomial  (yes/no) measures across two independent groups but I am not sure what test is most appropriate. Treating the group as the independent variable and the likerts as the dependent variables seems to very much lend itself to a MANOVA with post-hocs but is this a valid measure with likert and binomial data?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, the means and other summary statistics obtained from binary or ordinal data do not have normally distributed errors and are not homoscedastic. Strictly, ANOVA is not an appropriate tool to analyze such data.

There is a controversy in the literature on whether the violations of the assumptions of the ANOVA matter in practice and whether ANOVA should be used to analyze data from Likert scales. Some authors (Vigderhous, 1977; Knapp, 1990; Kuzon, Urbanchek & McCabe, 1996; Jakobsson, 2004; Jamieson, 2004) claim that non-parametric methods should be used instead of ANOVA. Other researchers (Pell, 2005; Carifio & Perla, 2008; Norman, 2010) argue that ANOVA is robust against the violations and since the choice of non-parametric methods results in a loss of power, ANOVA is preferable.

As O'Connell (2006) points out in the introduction to her book, there are methods that allow to map Likert scale data to an (latent) interval scale without throwing away the information provided by the data. In particular, I recommend the Ordered categorical regression as described by Gelman & Hill (2006) in chapters 6.5 and 15.2 of their book.

## Literature

Carifio, J., & Perla, R. (2008). Resolving the 50‐year debate around using and misusing Likert scales. Medical education, 42(12), 1150-1152.

Gelman, A., & Hill, J. (2006). Data analysis using regression and multilevel/hierarchical models. Cambridge university press.

Jakobsson, U. (2004). Statistical presentation and analysis of ordinal data in nursing research. Scandinavian Journal of Caring Sciences, 18(4), 437-440.

Jamieson, S. (2004). Likert scales: how to (ab) use them. Medical education, 38(12), 1217-1218.

Knapp, T. R. (1990). Treating ordinal scales as interval scales: an attempt to resolve the controversy. Nursing research, 39(2), 121-123.

Kuzon Jr, W. M., Urbanchek, M. G., & McCabe, S. (1996). The seven deadly sins of statistical analysis. Annals of plastic surgery, 37(3), 265-272.

Norman, G. (2010). Likert scales, levels of measurement and the “laws” of statistics. Advances in health sciences education, 15(5), 625-632.

O'Connell, A. A. (2006). Logistic regression models for ordinal response variables (No. 146). Sage.

Pell, G. (2005). Use and misuse of Likert scales. Medical Education, 39(9), 970-970.

Vigderhous, G. (1977). The level of measurement and “permissible” statistical analysis in social research. Pacific Sociological Review, 20(1), 61-72.